# PHP: When using get_template_part to load php partials how to wrap each part with <div>...</div> and toggle this wrapper on/off for debugging purpose

Tags: php, debugging, wordpress-theming

Q1. if get_template_part is used to load partials, Is there a way to inject

```
<div style="border: 1px solid blue"> around all partials </div>
```

so I can see the structure of my page and its partials for debugging purposes?

Q2.I would like to have a toggle that would do that for all partials loaded this way.

Q3.Eventually I would like to provide different border/backgroupd collors for partials loaded from different folders.

Q4.It would also be good to output partial names right after initial  wrapper so I can see where it comes from.

Q5.Even more ideally would be to have a link to a file like:

```
file://C://testwordpress/...Theme/partials/Details/myinfo.php
```

Here is my attempt as suggested by Levi:

php partial debugging
[php partial debugging](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radrad/radrad/main/phppartialdebugging1.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) documentation there is a hook before the template is loaded but not after so the answer to your first question is: **No**.

You can, however, create your own function something like...

```
function get_and_wrap_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null, array $args = [] ) {
    $depth = substr_count( $slug, '/' ) + 1;

    $color = 'hsl(' . ( $depth * 10 ) . 'deg, 100%, 50%)';

    echo '<div style="border: 1px solid ' . esc_attr( $color ) . '">';
        get_template_part( $slug, $name, $args );
    echo '<div>';
}
```

And then replace any usage of `get_template_part` with `get_and_wrap_template_part`.

This function will change the color of the border by counting the number of `/`'s in your template part giving you an indication of depth. Keep in mind that this coloring method only works up to a nesting depth of 36, any deeper the color will reset.

You can obviously modify this function to include things like the full path etc.

This might answer your question but it's definitley not a good idea. For starters you're going to run into a bunch of display issues, for example if one of your template parts is an inline element, wrapping it in a div (which is a block element) you will affect the layout of your page. Another example is if your CSS or JS depends on a specific structure i.e. `body > header` and your header is then wrapped in a div, the `body > header` selector wont work as the header is no longer a direct child of body.

Comment: Thankyou that is a good start. I will see if I will get more suggestion before accepting your answer.

Comment: How would I get a partial path which I need to review via link: file://...? I am new to php. Is there any other way to add this debugging metadata to visualize partials on the page and not distrupt CSS styling. I wanted minimal impact. What about doing something on hover so I can randomly go through the elements on the page and at that point metadata can surfice and some outline of the partial to appear. Maybe some kind of additional popup that doesn't disturbe the page structure, but provides extra information.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and somehow I can see only several parts being displayed at the bottom. there are many 100ths of them. Probably 30 on the page. See picture
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radrad/radrad/main/phppartialdebugging1.jpg